# Use a Persistence Entity like key

Tags: java, hibernate

There is a method to use a Persistence Entity like a key in an Embeddable class?

This is my code:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Embeddable
public class Key implements Serializable {

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    protected String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected User owner;

    public Key(){

    }

    public Key(String title, User owner){
        this.title = title;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

But I have this error:

> 'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Persistence Entity'

Comment: I think that what you're looking for is something like `@OneToOne`.

Comment: Is the User class inserted in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: @HenriqueMentz Yes! It is correctly insered

Comment: @chrylis It's possible that you have reasons. I try